# JavaScript onclick() event won't execute

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, model-view-controller, onclick

I want to save the name of a button when button is pressed.
Than I show a modal and redirect to a page using the button name.

JavaScript:

```
function onClickBtnRemove()
{
    deviceIdName = this.name;
}

function onClickBtnConfirmRemove() {
    window.location.href = "/Home/Remove/" + deviceIdName;    
}
```

html:

```
 <script> 
     var deviceIdName;
 </script>

<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="123" onclick="onClickBtnRemove()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#remove" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="remove" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4>Are you sure you want to remove this device?</h4>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="onClickBtnConfirmRemove()">Remove</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First question I have to make. Did you load the file on the html?

Comment: @LucasOliveira sure, in fact other onclick() events in my file are working.

Comment: You need to pass 'this' in the onclick handle and then receive as an argument in the handler and then use that argument to access the name attribute.

Comment: Though you should be using jquery for all this.